# Probability measure over finite sample space

Tags: probability-theory

This is a theorem from Casella and Berger's *Statistical Inference*:

> Let $S = \{s_1, \dots, s_n\}$ (sample space) be finite and $p_1,
>  \dots, p_n$ be nonnegative for all $i \in \{1, 2, \dots, n\}$ and
>   $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}p_i = 1$. For any $A \in \mathcal{B}$ (a
>   $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $S$), define $\mathbb{P}: \mathcal{B} \to [0, 1]$ by
>   $$\mathbb{P}(A) = \begin{cases}  \sum_{\{i \mid s_i \in A\}}p_i, & A
>  \neq \varnothing \\  0, & A = \varnothing\text{.}  \end{cases}$$  Then
>   $\mathbb{P}$ is a probability measure.

Is there supposed to be some correspondence between the $s_i$ and
 $p_i$? Some sort of correspondence is hinted with there being the same number of elements in $S$ and the number of $p_i$. My guess is that there's some sort of probability measure between them, i.e., $\mathbb{P}^{\prime}(s_i) = p_i$ if $\mathbb{P}^{\prime}$ is a probability measure.

Comment: More clearly, one starts with $p_i=\mathbb{P}(\{ s_i \})$ and then extends this to a probability measure on the whole $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @Ian If you want to post that as an answer, I will mark yours as best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More clearly, one starts with $p_i=\mathbb{P}(\{ s_i \})$ and then extends that to a probability measure on the whole $\sigma$-algebra.

Answer (score 2):

The expression $∑_{\{i∣s_i\in A\}}p_i$ should be interpreted as: sum $p_i$ over all $i$ for which $s_i$ belongs to $A$. So, for example, if the set $A$ contains the elements $s_1$, $s_7$, $s_{11}$ (and no other elements of $S$), then $\mathbb P(A)=p_1+p_7+p_{11}$. In particular, if $A=\{s_i\}$, then $\mathbb P(\{s_i\})=p_i$.

The theorem is valid no matter what $p_i$ you use, as long as they are nonnegative and sum to 1.